# Is there a nice nftables ruleset visualizer?

Tags: linux, software-rec, nftables

I have a rather large firewall ruleset in nftables. `nft list ruleset` is many pages.

It's possible to export the data in machine readable format (JSON), using `nft -j list ruleset`, but before I write my own, is there some nice human readable UI that formats this into nice tables?

I imagine something in the browser, that can reload the data and hilight changes in counters.

And also a graphviz-like graph showing dependencies between rules, as they `jump` and `goto`.